# xset not having any effect in my .xsessionrc file

Tags: x11, mouse, profile, session, xinit

I need to set some trackpoint settings automatically. I don't know the best file in which to place these commands, but I used `.xsessionrc`. The commands are properly executed (I can verify that by adding `set -x` in the script, I see the `xset` command being executed). The `xinput` command have their intended effect, but the `xset` command has no effect.

Can anyone help me figure out how to run all these commands, including `xset`, automatically?

Here are my commands:

```
xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Device Accel Profile" 7
xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.45
xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration" 40
xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 40
xset m 40 80
```

I can run the exact same `xset` command after I log in and it works as intended.

I run KDE (Kubuntu 14.10). Its GUI configuration doesn't have a way to set the parameters I want to set.

Comment: are you sure `.xsessinrc` is the right file (not `.xinitrc` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xset` command is executed, but something in KDE overrides these settings afterwards.

The easiest solution would be to find the place in KDE where you can set the mouse acceleration. [There may not be one though](https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/Mouse_pointer_settings_for_large_displays).

If you can't find a GUI way, you'll have to arrange for your `xset` command to run after KDE sets its own unmodifiable preferences. Add an [autostart script](https://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/autostart/).